Google Docs Testing via apps scripts
Okay, so i don’t really do scripting but I’ve learned a little along the way. I’ve only learned to use apps scripts so I would preferably need help using that. I’m a teacher who is trying to creat quizzes in a more effective way. I’m not sure if this is even possible but I was wondering if there is a script which can do the following output.
Let’s say the input are these few questions :

Which of the following is NOT a layer of the OSI Model?

a) Physical
b) Transfer
c) Presentation
d) Data Link
*b)

Which group was responsible for developing the OSI Model?

a) RSA
b) FBI
c) ISO
d) CIA
*c)

Which layer defines the electrical and physical specifications for devices?

a) Transfer
b) Network
c) Physical
d) Presentation
*c)
As you can see the answers are located at the bottom/end of the question symbolized by the asterisk.Is there any possible way where we can directly swap the answer with the asterisk to the right question without it replacing in every single question.
The output I would be looking for would be :

Which of the following is NOT a layer of the OSI Model?

a) Physical
*b)Transfer
c) Presentation
d) Data Link

Which group was responsible for developing the OSI Model?

a) RSA
b) FBI
*c) ISO
d) CIA

Which layer defines the electrical and physical specifications for devices?

a) Transfer
b) Network
*c) Physical
d) Presentation
Any help would be appreciated greatly.
I tried using the replace.bodytext command, but the problem is it would substitute for every single question rather then the one is should be assigned too.
